# Was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, working fine. now have only Grub prompt. What do I do now ?

Tags: 12.04

Laptop shut down due to errant battery. I was updating all programs on auto update option. Now all I have is a Grub> prompt. Where do I go from here.

Laptop is an NEC Versa and Ubuntu was working fine up until that moment without any issues.

Comment: Hi CJK.  You can boot into Ubuntu from a `grub>` prompt but it can be a little complicated, especially if you don't remember what your partition table looks like.  If you have access to a liveCD you can use the method in [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/63478) Q&A and it should fix the GRUB for you. If you don't have a liveCD or have problems please post as much and we will find another way.

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate on what error it's giving you?  Certain errors mean certain things.

Comment: @adempewolff Yup, I have needed to do that. Having a printed copy of your partition table ready in a waterproof chest really helps.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a grub rescue prompt, it is likely that grub cant find what is supposed to be booting. If it is just a generic grub prompt then it is likely something in boot files is messed up.

If you have a boot-cd that takes you into linux, I would suggest booting using that. mounting the drive under /mnt/my_drive, and running a chroot enviroment. the outline basics are bellow...

These commands require you to run them as a root/superuser, the prefered way to do this is prefix the commands with sudo , (alternatively you can use a root shell, created through running `sudo -s`). Which ever option you choose, beware, you can cause a lot of damage to your system using root, so use it with caution and sparingly.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my_drive
```

assuming your main partition is sda2

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/my_drve
```

then bind the /dev /proc /sys over to your hard drive

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/my_drive/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/my_drive/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/my_drive/sys
```

then move into a chroot environment

```
sudo chroot /mnt/my_drive /bin/bash
```

check that any package installations are configured

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

finally run the grub-install to repair the drive in question, often `/dev/sda`

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

and finally

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Don't forget `update-grub`

Comment: Also these commands need to be run as root, so either each needs a `sudo` prefix or the first command needs to be `sudo -s`